# npm run dev not running script

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack

I'm trying to run npm run dev on a project but i keep getting an error which i cant find an answer to. at first i figured it was a webpack error but i've uninstalled and reinstalled and still getting the error. i'm running node.js v10 which i cant update to the latest as other areas are dependent on v10.

This is the dev script im trying to run

```
 "dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=webpack.config.js"
```

this was my initial error:

```
#
# Fatal error in , line 0
# API fatal error handler returned after process out of memory
#
#
#
#FailureMessage Object: 000000EEFF5FA330npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 3221225477
npm ERR! Ffrees@1.0.0 dev: `cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=webpack.config.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 3221225477
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the Ffrees@1.0.0 dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\joe6166\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-06-13T20_36_55_273Z-debug.log
```

but now im getting this:

````
C:\Users\joe6166\code\UAccount>npm run dev
> Ffrees@1.0.0 dev C:\Users\joe6166\code\UAccount
> cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=webpack.config.js


<--- Last few GCs --->

[27056:0000023255CE98B0]   215447 ms: Mark-sweep 1345.6 (1442.9) -> 1330.1 (1439.9) MB, 750.4 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.277, current mu = 0.262) allocation failure scavenge might not succeed
[27056:0000023255CE98B0]   215717 ms: Scavenge 1344.8 (1439.9) -> 1330.7 (1440.9) MB, 4.3 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.277, current mu = 0.262) allocation failure


<--- JS stacktrace --->

==== JS stack trace =========================================

    0: ExitFrame [pc: 000000A16F1DC5C1]
    1: StubFrame [pc: 000000A16F1913E6]
Security context: 0x024cfb61e6c1 <JSObject>
    2: resolve [000001622EC02A61] [path.js:~133] [pc=000000A16FE7BE24](this=0x007738e82579 <Object map = 000002D088D38A71>)
    3: arguments adaptor frame: 1->0
    4: toNamespacedPath [000001622EC02BA1] [path.js:~609] [pc=000000A16FCD501C](this=0x007738e82579 <Object map = 000002D088D38A71>,path=0x03e132a8e6a1 <Very...

FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: 00007FF6EEE2879A v8::internal::GCIdleTimeHandler::GCIdleTimeHandler+4506
 2: 00007FF6EEE03206 node::MakeCallback+4534
 3: 00007FF6EEE03B80 node_module_register+2032
 4: 00007FF6EF121AFE v8::internal::FatalProcessOutOfMemory+846
 5: 00007FF6EF121A2F v8::internal::FatalProcessOutOfMemory+639
 6: 00007FF6EF308224 v8::internal::Heap::MaxHeapGrowingFactor+9620
 7: 00007FF6EF2FF206 v8::internal::ScavengeJob::operator=+24550
 8: 00007FF6EF2FD85C v8::internal::ScavengeJob::operator=+17980
 9: 00007FF6EF3065A7 v8::internal::Heap::MaxHeapGrowingFactor+2327
10: 00007FF6EF306626 v8::internal::Heap::MaxHeapGrowingFactor+2454
11: 00007FF6EF4308C7 v8::internal::Factory::NewFillerObject+55
12: 00007FF6EF4ADAB6 v8::internal::operator<<+73494
13: 000000A16F1DC5C1
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 134
npm ERR! Ffrees@1.0.0 dev: `cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=webpack.config.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 134
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the Ffrees@1.0.0 dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\joe6166\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-06-13T21_06_41_598Z-debug.log```
````

Comment: maybe like the error says you run out of memory

Comment: tried setting the memory with set ```NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=8192``` but still the same error

Comment: Did you run a `npm install` or `npm i` prior to the `npm run dev`? That is a prerequisite for futher npm commands.

This could also be important if you've manually edited your `package.json` file. You may need to run `npm i` again.

Also, these commands don't normally produce errors like this so it may be that you're running an old version of npm and/or node so perhaps it would be helpful to see the output of an `npm --version` and `node --version`.

Finally, if both are fairly modern, try deleting your `node_modules` and rerunning `npm i` before `npm run dev`.

Comment: Yeah ran npm install. im running npm v6.14.4 and node v10.20.1. need to keep node at version 10 as i need it for the version of gulp i have to work

Answer (score 0):

Does seem like a memory issue, maybe try `node --max_old_space_size=64` that may just work in v8 though.

Comment: Tried set ```NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=8192``` but didnt work